# How to only allow access to a page if it came from a link on my website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

On my website, I have the following files:

- *index.html*
- *apple.html*
- *banana.html*
- *pear.html*

*index.html* has links to the three other pages.

What is the easiest way to block access to the 3 pages (*apple.html*/*banana.html*/*pear.html*) unless their referrer came from a page which was on my website?

I have seen solutions where people put their website domain as the only referrer allowed. The problem with this is that I would have to set my domain every time, since I might upload my website to 10 different domains.

Is there any way to code the `.htaccess` so that it automatically detects the website domain where it's kept and use that as a reference to which referrer needs to be allowed?

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by "referrer"?

Comment: Do you want to only alllow `site.com/index.html -> site.com/apple.html` and no direct `site.com/apple.html` access?

Comment: Also, when you mean "block". What's the reason behind the blocking? Is it for security? I don't think you can achieve this in any way without it being able to be "hacked" somehow. If security is not important, you could use JS and store data in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: In a RewriteCond, you have access to several environment variables, such as HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This will check referer is present or not, 
After it will compare it with current domain.
If referer is different then it is from outside referer

```
{
   if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))) 
       {
          if (strtolower(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST)) != strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) 
            {
             // referer not from this domain. !! Access Denied  
            }
       }
}
```